# move the negative sign from the right side of number to left side in R languge

Tags: r

everyone,
In the csv file, if some number is negative, the negative is on right side, such as 56.17-. 
When importing to R language, I want to move the negative sign from right ride to left side to become a negative number, such as -56.17. However, if the number is negative number such as -56.17 or positive number 56.17, the number remains as negative or positive.Thank you so much.Dennis

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you imported the data successfully, at least? Into a dataframe, or what? Please include these details in your question. It will help make the question more focused.

Answer (score 4):

We can do this with `sub` to capture all the characters (`(.*)`) from the start (`^`) and match the `-` at the end (`$`) of the string, replace it with the `-` and the backreference (`\\1`) of the captured group

```
as.numeric(sub("^(.*)-$", "-\\1", v1))
#[1] -56.17 -56.17  56.17
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c('56.17-', -56.17, 56.17)
```

Comment: thank you so much, both of akrun and cptwonton. akrun's answer is perfect. have a good day.